# Adding an overlay to a full-screen video, how can it be done?

Tags: html, css, browser, jwplayer

So I have an application that allows users to stream video, built using RoR, JWPlayer and Bootstrap as the most important for this illustration.

I was able to add "teaser questions" to the end of the clip playing on JWPlayer as an overlay. These questions display at the end of the clip when it's not full screen.

However, when it's fullscreen the questions do NOT display. How can I add an overlay to the full screen mode? I understand this is at the browser level? Is there any way to accomplish this, even if it's a bit hacky - I'm OK with that.

Please advise!

Comment: This 100% not rails related

Comment: Agreed, removed. Thanks.

Comment: Could you send a link to a test page with the code you have? You should be able to accomplish this in fullscreen on desktop, but not on mobile. This page may help: https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/questions/16242138-jwplayer6-text-overlays-call-to-action

Comment: @JosieKeller, thanks! unfortunately the overlay option does not work in full-screen because the browser just disables fullscreen because DOM is changed. Any other ideas? Cheers!

Comment: @JosieKeller heres a test page I created just for you :) http://clipshout.com/test

Comment: @AnthonyPinto I don't see any overlay on the page (even when not in fullscreen). Do you have a test page with the code you're using?